# Efficient arithmetic special methods in Cython

Tags: python, cython

According to the Cython documentation regarding [arithmetic special methods](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/special_methods.html#arithmetic-methods) (operator overloads), the way they're implemented, I can't rely on `self` being the object whose special method is being called.

Evidently, this has two consequences:

1. I can't specify a static type in the method declaration. For example, if I have a class `Foo` which can only be multiplied by, say, an `int`, then I can't have `def __mul__(self, int op)` without seeing `TypeError`s (sometimes).
2. In order to decide what to do, I have to check the types of the operands, presumably using `isinstance()` to handle subclasses, which seems farcically expensive in an operator.

Is there any good way to handle this while retaining the convenience of operator syntax? My whole reason for switching my classes to Cython extension types is to improve efficiency, but as they rely heavily on the arithmetic methods, based on the above it seems like I'm actually going to make them worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the docs and my test results correctly, you actually can have a fast `__mul__(self, int op)` on a `Foo`, but you can only use it as `Foo() * 4`, not `4 * Foo()`. The latter would require an `__rmul__`, which is not supported, so it always raises `TypeError`.

The fact that the second argument is typed `int` means that Cython does the typecheck for you, so you can be sure that the left argument is really `self`.

Comment: You are correct, and I am considering going that route, but of course it doesn't retain the **full** convenience of the operator syntax.